# Como añadir imagen a correo enviado desde python

Tags: html, python, email, gmail

Estoy intentando añadir una imagen al final de un correo enviado desde python pero me esta dando error. Hasta el mensaje lo enviaba usando html e incluso podia añadir links sin ningun problema.

```
message = "<br>Hola %s,<br><br> Se ha detectado una alerta de seguridad <br><br> Si este cambio ha sido voluntario, por favor, ignore este mensaje. De lo contrario por favor hago acceda al siguiente link para localizar su SIM y desactivarla: <br><br> <center><a href='https://ponteaprueba.com/response'> Localizar y desactivar SIM </a><br><br></center>    Muchas gracias,<br><br>    Equipo de Soporte ponteaprueba<br> <img src ="http://cdn.revistagq.com/uploads/images/thumbs/es/gq/3/s/2016/13/tipologias_foto_whastapp_606053640_511x384.jpg" alt="firma">" % (customer, iccid)
mime_message = MIMEText(message, "html", _charset = "uft-8")
mime_message["From"] = "ponteaprueba@gmail.com"
mime_message["To"] = recipient
mime_message["Subject"] = "Alert"
#We try to make the conection with the SMTP server
smtp = SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
smtp.ehlo()
smtp.starttls()
smtp.ehlo()
print "Conexion exitosa con Gmail"
print "Concectado a Gmail"
#We introduce the credentials of the sender in the SMTP server and send the email.
smtp.login(username, pass)
smtp.sendmail(username,recipient,mime_message.as_string())
smtp.quit()
return "Mensaje enviado"
```

¿Puede ser porque es una imagen de internet? ¿Existe alguna forma de coger una imagen igual que haces con un link?

Gracias

Comment: ¿Exactamente cuál es el mensaje de error que te esta dando?

Comment: La cadena `mensaje` esta mal construida (debes recibir un error de sintaxis),  si la cadena usa comillas dobles para delimitarse, dentro usa solo comillas simples.  Por otro lado usas dos parámetros para formatear la cadena `customer`y `iccid` pero solo usas uno en la cadena, esto dará también error, si uno no hace falta quitalo y si hacen falta en la cadena añade el `%s` correspondiente en el lugar que toque.

Comment: Perfecto, ya funciona!! Muchas gracias FJSevilla. Espero verte en todas mis preguntas :)

Comment: @FJSevilla: Sería bueno que agregaras tu comentario como respuesta.

Comment: @Rubén pues en su momento dudé si crear o no una pregunta porque me parecía mas bién un error tipográfico que otra cosa (además de que el OP no especificaba el error concreto que obtenia). No obstante llegados a este punto y, dado que además del problema de las comillas hay otro error en la construcción de la cadena, he creado una respuesta algo más extendida, para que pueda ser de más ayuda en otros casos similares, como recomiendas. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en que la cadena `mensaje` está mal construida. Usas el mismo tipo de comillas que usas para delimitar la cadena, como caractéres dentro de ella, sin escapar estos caractéres adecuadamente. Esto rompe tu cadena. Por ejemplo:

```
>>> cadena = "Dime "hola""
```

Dará un error de sintaxis:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

En Python puedes crear una cadena usando comillas simples (`'cadena'`), dobles (`"cadena"`) o triples (`'''cadena'''`). Si necesitas usar las comillas como un carácter cualquiera dentro de tu cadena, tienes dos opciones:

- Usar una secuecia de escape:

  ```
  cadena = "Dime \"hola\""
  ```
- Usar un tipo de comillas como delimitador y otro como carácter interno:

  ```
  cadena = 'Dime "hola"'
  cadena = '''Dime "hola"'''
  cadena = "Dime 'hola'"
  ```

En tu caso lo más simple (menos cambios requiere) es usar comillas simples para delimitar la cadena y dobles dentro de ella.

Por otro lado usas dos parámetros para formatear la cadena `customer`y `iccid` pero solo usas uno en la cadena, esto dará también error:

> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Si uno no hace falta, quítalo. Si hacen falta los dos, añade el %s correspondiente en el lugar que toque.

Para terminar, el uso de % para formatear cadenas es válido pero considera algo "anticuado" en favor del método `str.format` o incluso de los [literales de cadena formateados](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) (Python 3.6) que son más trasparentes y más flexibles (permitiendo por ejemplo tabular datos fácilmente):

```
nombre = 'Juan'
edad = 24

# Usando % como en c

cad1 = 'Hola me llamo %s y tengo %i años.' % (nombre, edad))

# Usando el método str.format
cad2 = 'Hola me llamo {} y tengo {} años.'.format(nombre, edad))

# Usando literales de cadena formateados (Python >= 3.6):
cad3 = f'Hola me llamo {nombre} y tengo {edad} años.'

print(cad1, cad2, cad3, sep='\n')
```

**Salida:**

> Hola me llamo Juan y tengo 24 años.
>   Hola me llamo Juan y tengo 24 años.
>   Hola me llamo Juan y tengo 24 años.

Answer (score 1):

```
# Importamos librerías
import smtplib
import mimetypes

# Importamos los módulos necesarios
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEImage import MIMEImage
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

# Creamos objeto Multipart, quien será el recipiente que enviaremos
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From']="Remitente@gmail.com"
msg['To']="Destinatario@gmail.com"
msg['Subject']="Alarma Activada"
msg.attach(MIMEText("La alarma de movimiento ha sido activada, verifique la integridad de su vivienda."))

# Adjuntamos Imagen
file = open("Imagen.jpg", "rb")
attach_image = MIMEImage(file.read())
attach_image.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename = "Alarma"')
msg.attach(attach_image)

# Autenticamos
mailServer = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
mailServer.ehlo()
mailServer.starttls()
mailServer.ehlo()
mailServer.login("Destinario@gmail.com","Password")

# Enviamos
mailServer.sendmail("Destinatario@gmail.com", "Remitente@gmail.com", msg.as_string())

# Cerramos conexión
mailServer.close()
```

Este código funciona para enviar una imagen adjunta, espero sea de utilidad

Comment: Bueno, yo lo que realmente busco es enviar la imagen como una firma al final del correo no como adjunto :(